# Query issue when using NOT IN and the sub-select returns NULLs

Tags: mysql

I' am trying to figure it out what am doing wrong in here. Basically the Query below Queries the table "**Profiles**" **t1** and then again Using NOT IN Function Queries same table "**Profiles**" and gets the profile_friends from **t2** and shows the results of ids that are not found on **t2** results.

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.profile_id,  t1.profile_username, t1.profile_name, t1.profile_friends 
FROM PROFILES t1
WHERE t1.profile_id NOT IN (SELECT t2.profile_friends FROM PROFILES AS t2 WHERE t2.profile_id = '1')
```

**Results from above Query and Database Structure**
[image]

This ID's  **2,6,10** should not show in this result. Well ID **2** is not showing but why is ID **6** and **10** are showing?

But When I try this code it works (Note that I have hard coded the values)

```
SELECT t1.profile_id,  t1.profile_username, t1.profile_name, t1.profile_friends 
FROM PROFILES t1
WHERE t1.profile_id NOT IN (2,6,10)
```

Comment: If you change your `SELECT` subquery to exclude `NULL`'s from being within your `NOT IN` filter, does that change your results?

Comment: I have a drawer of socks. If I turn off the light and randomly select some socks from it, why do I only seem to get red ones and green ones?

Answer (score 2):

You have to take `NULL`s into consideration. Any usual comparison (=, <>, >, <) with `NULL` gives `NULL`. The proper comparison for `NULL` is `IS NULL`

Also it looks like there is no need for a subquery in your case.

```
SELECT *
  FROM profiles
 WHERE profile_id <> 1
   AND (profile_friends <> '1' OR profile_friends IS NULL) -- parentheses are important here
```

Sample output:

```
| PROFILE_ID | PROFILE_USERNAME | PROFILE_FRIENDS |
|------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          3 |        username3 |          (null) |
|          4 |        username4 |          (null) |
|          5 |        username5 |          (null) |
|          7 |        username7 |          (null) |
|          8 |        username8 |          (null) |
|          9 |        username9 |          (null) |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb8814/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks but there seems to be a slightly misunderstanding. Please see my update "Results from above Query and Database Structure "